# Posts all share the same comments instead of each one having unique comments iOS Social Media App

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uikit

I am currently working on a social media app on Xcode 14.2. At this point, I am up to integrating a functional comments system, where users can view existing comments for a post and leave their own. I have gotten it to work somewhat, as an issue is plaguing me.

How it currently works is that under each post there would be a text symbol that functions as a button. When the user presses the button, they get redirected to the comments section, where they can view what other users say as well as make their own by pressing the create comment button. The issue is that when a user leaves a comment, the comment shows up underneath all of the existing posts on the app, rather than just the post the user chose to comment on. How do I go about making sure each post has its own unique comments section such that when a user leaves a comment it only shows on that post, rather than having the comment show across all posts?

Here is the code involved:
`CommentViewController`

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class CommentViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    
        var selectedPost: PFObject!
        var comments: [PFObject] = []
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        loadComments()
    }
    
    func loadComments()
    {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
            query.whereKey("post", equalTo: selectedPost)
            query.includeKey("author")
            query.findObjectsInBackground
            {
            
                [weak self] comments, error in
                if let comments = comments
                {
                    self?.comments = comments
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                } else if let error = error
                {
                    print("Error loading comments: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
    }


    @IBAction func onCreateComment(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Comment", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField
        {
            textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter your comment here"
        }
        
        let postAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Post", style: .default)
        {
            [weak self] _ in
            
            guard let commenttext = alertController.textFields?.first?.text
                    else
            {
                return
            }
            
            let newComment = PFObject(className: "Comment")
            newComment["author"] = PFUser.current() ?? NSNull()
            newComment["text"] = commenttext
            newComment["post"] = self?.selectedPost ?? NSNull()
            newComment.saveInBackground
            {
                [weak self] success, error in
                if success
                {
                    self?.loadComments()
                }
                else if let error = error
                {
                    print("Error saving comment: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(postAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return comments.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
        
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.commentTextLabel.text = comment["text"] as? String
        
        if let user = comment["author"] as? PFUser
        {
            cell.nameLabel.text = user.username
        }
        else
        {
            cell.nameLabel.text = "Unknown"
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    }
```

`CommentCell`

```
import UIKit

class CommentCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Any and all feedback/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Update: I have changed `selectedPost` to `postObject`. The way CommentViewController works in terms of an instance of it being made is there's a button in `FeedViewController` connected to it that presents modally when pressed. The following is how my `CommentViewController` looks now.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class CommentViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    
        var postObject: PFObject!
        var comments: [PFObject] = []
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        if postObject != nil
        {
            loadComments()
        }
    }
    
    func loadComments()
    {
        guard let postObject = postObject else
        {
            print("Error: postObject is nil")
            return
        }
        
        guard let postId = postObject.objectId else
        {
            print("Error: postId is nil")
            return
        }

        let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        postQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: postId)

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
        query.whereKey("post", equalTo: postObject)
        query.whereKey("post", matchesQuery: postQuery)
        query.includeKey("author")
        query.findObjectsInBackground
        {
            [weak self] comments, error in
            if let comments = comments
            {
                self?.comments = comments
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            } else if let error = error
            {
                print("Error loading comments: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            }
    }


    @IBAction func onCreateComment(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Comment", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField
        {
            textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter your comment here"
        }
        
        let postAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Post", style: .default)
        {
            [weak self] _ in
            
            guard let commenttext = alertController.textFields?.first?.text
                    else
            {
                return
            }
            
            let newComment = PFObject(className: "Comment")
            newComment["author"] = PFUser.current() ?? NSNull()
            newComment["text"] = commenttext
            newComment["post"] = self?.postObject ?? NSNull()
            newComment.saveInBackground
            {
                [weak self] success, error in
                if success
                {
                    self?.loadComments()
                }
                else if let error = error
                {
                    print("Error saving comment: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(postAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return comments.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CommentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
        
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.commentTextLabel.text = comment["text"] as? String
        
        if let user = comment["author"] as? PFUser
        {
            cell.nameLabel.text = user.username
        }
        else
        {
            cell.nameLabel.text = "Unknown"
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    }
```

Sadly I still get the error postObject is nil.

Update 3: Here is some code from `FeedViewController` that involves `postObject` and `CommentViewController`

````
var postObject: PFObject?

//...

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let commentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentViewController") as! CommentViewController
        
        if let postObject = postObject
        {
            commentVC.postObject = postObject
        }
        
        present(commentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Are you sure that `selectedPost` is being set? The code you have sets a comment's post to null if it isn't. So maybe all of your comments have a null post instead of the specific post.

Comment: It should be. When I go to create a comment it fully works it displays the comment I make and stays there when I leave the comments section of the post and rejoin it. The main thing is just having each post have its own unique comments section. Do you think maybe there's something I'm missing in ```loadComments()```

Comment: *"It should be."* - you need to confirm this. Use the debugger and check. I don't use Parse but if it has some interface that lets you browse the data, verify the records in the Comment table and verify whether the comments have appropriate post values or not.

Comment: I just checked my parse dashboard. In the Comments class, the comments I make on a post does show up there. The database does have them saved it's just a matter of having the comment be only shown when the user goes to the comments section of the post he/she left the comment under rather than have it show up on every single post.

Comment: Update: after doing some debugging, I found that ```selectedPost``` is indeed being read as nil. Working to see what I can do.

Comment: Update 2:  Struggling to deal with the ```selectedPost``` is nil error. Been trying different things to instantiate/set ```selectedPost```, nothing has been working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the `didSelectRowAt` method of your `FeedViewController`. Going on the assumption that each row in `FeedViewController` represents one post, you need to get the post object for the selected row.

I'll assume `FeedViewController` has an array of posts in a property named `posts` (adjust to whatever you are actually using). Given that, your `didSelectRowAt` method would need to be something like the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let commentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentViewController") as! CommentViewController
    commentVC.postObject = posts[indexPath.row]
    
    present(commentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In other words, get the post object for the selected row much like you probably do in your `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Good news and bad news.

Good news: Whenever I tap on the post, a new view controller pops up.

Bad news: There's no way for me to make a new comment and I am trying to have it be where when I tap the text button underneath the post, it takes me to the CommentViewController where I can view and create comments that show up only for that individual post.

Comment: Is your good/bad news in any way related to my answer? All I had you change was how the `postObject` was obtained and set. Nothing else should have changed in your code. You were able to create comments before. My answer would not have changed that in the slightest.

Comment: I implemented your answer in my code however I got the comment functionality to work in terms of viewing and adding comments. However, the root of the problem still remains. When I add a comment, it shows up on all the posts, rather than the post I comment on. I want to make it so each post has its own unique comments.

Comment: That's what my suggested change was meant to resolve. It ensure that your CommentViewController is given the proper post so new comments are created with the correct post and your code to query the comments should only give the comments for that one post. But let me ask one more question to be absolutely clear. On what screen are you seeing the new comment appear for all posts? Is it the CommentViewController or some other screen?

Comment: The CommentViewController is what displays the comments and lets the user create a comment. It's on that screen that I see the comment appear for all posts rather than have it show the comment on the post I choose to comment on.

Comment: finally got it to work. I just had to change 
``` commentVC.postObject = posts[indexPath.row]```
to
```commentVC.postObject = posts[indexPath.section]```
and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user16961399 Perfect. Yeah, I guessed at that line as I stated in the answer. Glad you figured out what it needed to be.